# Find the number of combination of 5 digit numbers satisfying the following condition.

Tags: combinatorics

> A five digit number $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5$ is formed using non zero digits. Condition 1 is that $a_i\leq a_j\forall i<j$ and condition 2 is that $a_i\geq a_j\forall i<j$ . If the probability that either of the conditions is satisfied is P, then find the value of [100P]. (were [x] denotes greatest integer less than or equal to x)

Considering first condition:
In the given number $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5$ let us take $a_5$ to be as 7,
then $a_4$ can take values {$1,2,...,7$}.Similarly $a_3$ can take different values based on the value taken of $a_4$ from the set above.
Now for the both condition to be satisfied there is no other way but all the digits  to be equal i.e. $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=a_5$
But here I am unable to find the number of combination of numbers for each of the conditions given.I don't have any ideas how to proceed.If we use the idea as I mentioned above all the way down to $a_1$ then its nothing but manually counting all the combinations.
I literally cannot think of any other method. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For condition $1$: place a $1$ in front of the number and a $9$ behind it, then look at the six differences of consecutive digits. Other condition is similar.

Comment: @WimC I didn't get you.

Comment: The point to note is that once you choose five digits, the number is fixed. You cannot permute them. For example, if you choose digits as $1, 3, 6, 6, 9$ then for condition $1$, the number is $96631$. So the solution is number of ways to choose $5$ digits from digits $1-9$ with repetition allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $5$ identical balls to be put in numbered bins $1\;thru\;9$ from left to right

Then by stars and bars, number of possible placements = $\binom {5+9-1}{9-1}$

Looking from left to right, it satisfies condition $1$,
and looking from right to left, it satisfies condition $2$

But we have counted the all equal numbers twice, and need to correct this.

Can you proceed from here ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to be of help !